# "Over promise under perform" motto

Tags: idiom, motto

As this is the time when we're all coming up with wacky mottos, I thought I'd try my hand at our department's private motto.

Having run a few variants through Google Translate, and coming out with a Latin word salad, I thought I'd try my old Latin dictionary. It still comes out as a poor Anglophone substitution rather than a witty slogan.

"We overpromise, (and) we under-perform"

Overpromise, as in "to promise the earth". To claim that we can and will do more than your "wildest dreams could imagine". That's the first idiomatic sticking point.

Under-perform, as in lacklustre, shoddy or slapdash. I'm sure there's a pretty way of saying that, other than "sub-optimal".

And then how to stick them together in a way that doesn't hurt to look at?

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question!

Comment: @Rafael Happy to be here and thanks for the warm welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is *nimium promittimus, parum patramus.*

*nimium* and *parum* are adverbs meaning 'too much'/'excessively' and 'too little'/'insufficiently', respectively.

*promittimus* means 'we promise,' and *patramus* means 'we carry through'/'we bring to completion'/'we accomplish.' Both verbs are being used 'absolutely' here, without the direct object that they would typically have. The pairing of these two verbs can be found in, e.g., Cicero, *Ad Atticum* 1.14.7:

> nunc ut ad privata redeam, Τεῦκρις **promissa patravit**.

So the sentence literally means, 'We promise excessively, (but) we carry through to completion insufficiently.'

Comment: There's always a danger of over-elaborating into something uncomfortably pseudo-Latin in cases like this. The short and direct mottoes are always best.

Comment: I was mulling over nimis rather than nimium to match parum. Couldn't find matching verbs: +1 patro

Answer (score 6):

Here's a ready-made Latin motto. It was widely known and widely used but this is the neatest version (Horace: [Ars Poetica, 136–9](https://archive.org/stream/satiresepistlesa00horauoft#page/462/mode/2up))

> Parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus

literally it means "The Alps will be giving birth:  A ridiculous mouse pops out!"
It is cryptic enough to have a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mountain_in_Labour) page, "The Mountain in Labour." There's a longer version by Aesop.

Comment: That's hilarious! I can see some situations where that will come in handy and I love the idiom, but that's perhaps one layer of subtlety too deep..

Comment: This allusion to Aesop sounds perfect for this motto! If taking Horace's line _in toto_ is too obscure, what do you think of something like **Montes propositi, mures redditi**?

Answer (score 2):

For "overpromise" there's a nice idiomatic expression: ***marĭa montesque pollĭcēmur***. It means literally "we promise the sea and the mountains", pretty close to "promise the earth". It has remained intact in the Italian *promettere mari e monti*.

There is no single verb to express a sub-optimal performance, but I like ***ad ultimum non pervĕnīmus*** - literally, "we don't reach the highest/furthest", i.e. "we don't reach perfection". Plus, I think it looks good with the sea and mountains metaphore.

To sum it up:

> Maria montesque pollicemur, ad ultimum non pervenimus.

Comment: Perfectly balanced, as all mottos should be.

Answer (score 1):

A, rather literal, translation would be:

> **Multa promittimus, pauca adimplemus**

- [Promitto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpromitto) means, among other things, *to promise*. **Promittimus** → *we promise*.
- **Multa** is the plural neuter form of [multus, -a, -um](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmultus), *many*. The use of pl. neut. is an idiomatic way of saying *many things*.
- In a similar way, **pauca** is pl. n. for [paucus, -a, -um](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpaucus), *few things*.
- [Adimpleo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dadimpleo) means *to fulfill* (also with other meanings). **Adimplemus** → *we fulfill*.

A close quote may be found in the Gospel of St. Matthew:

> **Super pauca fuisti fidelis; supra multa te constituam** ([NVG Mt. 25:21](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_evang-matthaeum_lt.html#25)) *you were faithful in small matters, I will give you great responsibilities* ([NABRE](http://www.usccb.org/bible/matthew/25#48025021))